# How to make geometric nodes have physical simulation？

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make the instance on the geometry nodes have the attributes of physical simulation, or be driven, how should I achieve the main effect, in short, how does the geometric node have physical simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it isn't possible as you want to have it... but of course you can add rigid body to your object, which has geometry nodes modifier. But it will take the mesh "as one" into account, not single pieces.

So you can do things like this:

[image]

But AFAIK you cannot let all single pieces fall down...yet. Maybe and hopefully in the future.

Comment: thanks！chris，hope the future coming in

Comment: can i have your photo blend file work ？it look very cool

Comment: @TANDG: here is the link where i have learnt the technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5eNdCpoRD4